# How to bind an ObservableCollection to a combobox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, observablecollection

I'm stuck with this and even after reading a lot of topics I can find the answer.

Here my attempt to bind an observable Collection to a combobox in WPF using MVVM Pattern:

**Scenario.cs**

```
{
    public class Scenario
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string codeClient { get; set; }
        public string codeAppli { get; set; }
        public string infoComplementaire { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**scenarioVM.cs**

```
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }
    }
```

**MainWindows.xaml**

`<ComboBox x:Name="cbScenario" ItemsSource="{Binding Scenarios}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="407,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" BorderBrush="#FF1585B5" Height="26"/>`

Thanx for the help :)

Comment: how do you set DataContext in MainWindow?

Comment: Like this : public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            this.Loaded += MetroWindow_Loaded;
        }

Comment: Try DisplayMemberPath="Name"

Comment: Hi Niklas, i did but its not working either

Comment: Might be a stupid question but to be sure, your ObservableCollection has items?

Comment: Yes I have all the items I need in the observableCollection but can bind it to the Combo Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your `DataContext` to `this`, ofc you can't find `Scenarios` if its part of your `ScenarioVM` and not your Window. `DataContext` is the root of any Binding.

For a start you could do this.

```
public ScenarioVM VM {get; private set;}

public MainWindow() 
{ 
    VM = new ScenarioVM();
    InitializeComponent(); 
    DataContext = VM; 
    this.Loaded += MetroWindow_Loaded; 

    VM.Scenarios.Add(new Scenario());
}
```

Now your window owns an instance of the ScenarioVM. Not necessarily a good design, but a start.

Also sooner than later you run into Trouble that your Scenario is not deriving from `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you might want to address that as well.

Comment: Sorry but it s not working, now I have a nullReferenceException. How can I make it a better design?

Comment: You probably have a null ref when adding to Scenarios, i assumed that to be part of your not shown code. So initialize it before hand.